# Laravel Nova Datetime field showing wrong value

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-nova, laravel-10

I have an event model with two properties. `start_at` and `end_at`.

I have a Laravel Nova instance to edit the props. For some reason, it shows incorrectly in the dashboard.

Database shows:

[image]

But in Nova,  the fields shows for both fields: 2024-01-15 00:00:00

[image]

Props defined in Nova are

```
DateTime::make('Start At'),
DateTime::make('End At'),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if the timezone of nova is the same as the database

Comment: @LucasPace should that be the same as Lararavel (UTC)?

Comment: By default, laravel nova use the same timezone of laravel. But you can change it in `NovaServiceProvider`.
Your database is hosted in local? And what database are you using?

Comment: This is due to the timezone. Set the correct timezone and in the model set `cast`date `protected $casts = [
    'start_at' => 'datetime',
    'end_at' => 'datetime',
];`